# HTML Elements in my WP Plugin being generated in JS. Security and Translated Text Question about this method being used

Tags: plugin-development, security, translation

So unfortunately when developing my WP plugin I created some methods that will help me generate HTML elements and their attributes with `document.createElement`.

One example function is provided below. (this block of code is not important for the question)

```
    // Create HTML Elements for the form/etc. elements to be added.
    createHTMLElements = (data: CreateFormData[]): HTMLElement[] => {
        let formElements: HTMLElement[] = [];

        for (const entry of data)...

        // Create the HTML element based on parameters passed.

        return formElements;
    }
```

The type of html being generated are `<input>, <form>, <button>, <a>` etc. They are all user inputs that is going to be sent to the back-end with ajax requests so they have to be escaped.

This issue I am running into is since most of the HTML generation is in JS I am not able to use esc_*_e to properly implement security on my plugin. Also, I realized there will be issues with translating text since there is no standard way through wordpress from js to attach a `text-domain` for the tranlsator. (at least to the best of my knowledge).

Before I re-do everything into PHP that is done in JS, I had some questions.

1. If I decide to keep everything in JS, would that be a major security risk for XSS? Even if I escape it with custom made JS functions?
2. Is there any way to attach a text-domain onto an attribute or html when escaping it through JS? I only ask cause maybe I can handle that in JS with a custom function.

It is looking like that I will be having to rewrite everything in PHP but I figured I should ask before I start the many lines of code to convert. Appreciate any help and thanks for your time.

Comment: There's not enough context here to answer #1. What is being output? What is the source? Why is it being output in JavaScript? Regarding #2, see: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/11/09/new-javascript-i18n-support-in-wordpress/

Comment: Good point, I will update the question after this. So what is being generated are mainly <inputs> <forms> <buttons> <a>, etc. all with many attributes depending on the situation, Atributes such as name, url, src, etc. Nearly all of this will be user inputs so they have to be escaped. I hope this is enough context.

Comment: Is there a reason they're being generated with JavaScript and not in a template?

Comment: It was a foolish error on my part. I wanted to try using mostly JS and ran into this issue.